# Express API response directly outputted in browser instead being handled by Nuxt.js

Tags: node.js, vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

I have an express server that is connected to mongodb. I have a nuxt route for `/account` under pages directory. I also have a same route in the express server `app.use('/account', account)` which is handling the requests.

The database model has been set correctly and the response is sent by the server using `return res.status(200).json(User)` whenever the route is called upon using a get request. I'm also seeing the response being delivered to the browser.

But the problem is the response is being outputted directly in the browser as raw json. Nuxt is not being loaded to handle the response. I haven't setup any $axios data call in the component using `asyncdata` or `fetch` yet.

Here's the sample response that i see in the browser

`{"email":"sample@example.com","account":"123445667777"}`

I'm not sure what the issue is?

Comment: How do you call the `/account`, are you directly typing the URL in browser like `localhost:3000/account` ?

Comment: Yes when i type the url, it seems like the first /account request connects to the server and delivers the result in the browser and ends the request

Comment: this is a correct behavior, you need use `Async Data` for MVC,then only the NuxtJS will take it, refer this `https://nuxtjs.org/guide/async-data`

Comment: `async asyncData() {
        await this.$axios.get('/')
            .then((response) => {
                console.log(response);
            })
            .catch((error) => {
            }) 
},`

I tried this inside the component but still the same issue